# Prove that the only invariant point under a dilation with center $C$ is itself, and the only invariant lines under a dilation are lines through $C$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Assuming the dilation is non-identity (r$\neq $ 1).

It's a straight forward proof to show that $C$ is the only invariant point under the dilation, using the equation $C'=$ $D_C,r$ $(C)$.

$C=$($c_1$, $c_2$, $1$) and $D_C,r$ = $\begin{bmatrix}r&0&c_1\left(1-r\right)\\ \\0&r&c_2\left(1-r\right)\\ \\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ .

But I can't come up with a method to show that all lines incident with center $C$ are invariant.

Comment: Your line of formulas is unclear, you defined only the symbol $C$ (as the center of the dilation).

Comment: What did you try? What is the (analytical if you prefer) description of your dilation? (and in which space?)

Comment: You would appear to be talking about [homogeneous dilations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothety) on a [projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane).  Is that the case?  If so, then your taking $\ C\ $ to have coordinates $\ c_1,c_2\ $ and $\ 1\ $ means that your proof that it's the "only invariant under the dilation" wouldn't quite be complete, since it doesn't cover the case when $\ C\ $ is a point on the line at infinity.  For a complete proof, you'd need to let your coordinates of  $\ C\ $ be  *any* three scalars $\ c_1,c_2\ $ and $\ c_3\ $, not all zero.

Comment: It's also puzzling that you're looking at proofs for just one very specific special case when the result holds for homogeneous dilations on any [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space), and the proofs will be essentially the same for that general case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on how you define a line.

You can define a line as the set of points $ax+by+d=0$. Then the homogeneous coordinates $[a:b:d]$ describe the line. Homogeneous here means that multiples of these numbers represent the same set of points. $3ax+3by+3d=0$ is the same line.

How does your matrix act on a line? A point lies on the transformed line if it is the image of a point on the original line. As a formula, you have the original point lying on the original line as

$$[a,b,d]\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}=0$$

and then the transformed point lies on the transformed line

$$\left([a,b,d]\cdot D_{C,r}^{-1}\right)\cdot\left(D_{C,r}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=0$$

So if you represent the line as a row vector, you multiply that with the inverse of your transformation matrix from the right. If you treat your line as a column vector and use dot product between that and the point, then you multiply the inverse transpose transformation matrix from the left.

So where does all this lead? You are looking for a vector which, when multiplied with a matrix, changes perhaps its magnitude but not its direction. That's an eigenvector problem. You want to show that all lines through $C$ are eigenvectors of the inverse (and possibly transpose) matrix, belonging to an eigenspace of dimension two. (You would also find the line at infinity as another eigenvector of any affine transformation.)

If you represent your lines in a different way, say using a pair of distinct points, or point and direction, then your approach would likely be different. I'll leave this for other answers to cover.